# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so'

Tags: php, mongodb

I installed php `7.2` and mongodb `3.4` on centos `7.4`,
there is an error when I run php command,like this:

```
[root@vagrant-dev ~]# php artisan migrate
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: artisan
```

what should I do?